# String matching to data.frames of different sizes

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have two data.frames of different sizes and I'm looking for the most efficient way to match strings from one data.frame to another, and extract some relevant information.

Here is an example:

Two initial data.frames, a and b, and the desired result:

```
a = data.frame(term = c("red", "salad", "rope", "ball", "tent", "plane", "gift", "meat"),
               age = c(30, 24, 52, 44, 73, 44, 33, 12),
               visits = c(5, 1, 3, 2, 8, 5, 19, 3))

b = data.frame(string = c("the red ball went over the fence",
                          "sorry to see that your tent fell down",
                          "the ball fell into the red salad",
                          "serious people eat peanuts on Sundays"))

desired_result = data.frame(string = b$string,
                            num_matches = c(2, 1, 3, 0),
                            avg_age = c(37, 73, 32.66667, NA),
                            avg_visits = c(3.5, 8, 2.66667, NA))
```

Here are the data.frames in a more readable format:

```
> a
   term age visits
1   red  30      5
2 salad  24      1
3  rope  52      3
4  ball  44      2
5  tent  73      8
6 plane  44      5
7  gift  33     19
8  meat  12      3

> b
                                 string
1      the red ball went over the fence
2 sorry to see that your tent fell down
3      the ball fell into the red salad
4 serious people eat peanuts on Sundays

> desired_result
                                 string num_matches  avg_age avg_visits
1      the red ball went over the fence           2 37.00000    3.50000
2 sorry to see that your tent fell down           1 73.00000    8.00000
3      the ball fell into the red salad           3 32.66667    2.66667
4 serious people eat peanuts on Sundays           0       NA         NA
```

- num_matches is the number of "terms" in "string"
- avg_age is the mean age of the "terms" found in "string"
- avg_visits is the mean number of visits of the "terms" found in "string"

Any ideas on how to implement this in an efficient way?

Thank you.

Comment: avg_age and avg_visits can also be equal to zero if no matches are found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `data.table`, process each row with `by = string`. save the match results in a list, then aggregate by the match results.

Note the `matches` column is a list of list, each cell holding a list. You need wrap the match results with `.()` which is actually another `list()` because data.table expect a list for normal columns.

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
a = data.table(term = c("red", "salad", "rope", "ball", "tent", "plane", "gift", "meat"),
  age = c(30, 24, 52, 44, 73, 44, 33, 12),
  visits = c(5, 1, 3, 2, 8, 5, 19, 3))
b = data.table(string = c("the red ball went over the fence",
  "sorry to see that your tent fell down",
  "the ball fell into the red salad",
  "serious people eat peanuts on Sundays"))

b[, matches := vector("list", .N)]
b[, matches := .(list(str_detect(string, a[, term]))), by = string]
b[, num_matches := sum(unlist(matches)), by = string]
b[, avg_age := mean(a[unlist(matches), age]), by = string]
b[, avg_visits := mean(a[unlist(matches), visits]), by = string]
```

Comment: Thank you to all the respondents... I like this solution a lot b/c of how clear each of the steps are (making it easier to add additional steps/complexity).  It also uses str_detect which uses the entire string and generalizes to terms that aren't a single word.  Note: added "na.rm = T" to "sum(unlist(matches))" and "b[, matches:=NULL]" to remove the matches column at the end

Answer (score 2):

You can try this with base R (no package is needed):

```
res <- t(apply(b, 1, function(x) {
    l <- strsplit(x, " ")
    r <- unlist(lapply(unlist(l), function(y) which(a$term==y)))
    rbind(length(r), mean(a$age[r]), mean(a$visits[r]))

}))

res <- cbind(b, res)
                                 # string 1        2        3
# 1      the red ball went over the fence 2 37.00000 3.500000
# 2 sorry to see that your tent fell down 1 73.00000 8.000000
# 3      the ball fell into the red salad 3 32.66667 2.666667
# 4 serious people eat peanuts on Sundays 0      NaN      NaN
```

Comment: strsplit could be limited if the string is a little bit messy, like `plane's`.

Answer (score 0):

I would build up `desired_result` one part after the other:

Therefore you need two functions one to count and one to compute the average.

First for the occurrences:

```
  counter <- function(sentence, pattern)
  { 
      count <-0
      for (var in pattern)
      {
         if(grepl(pattern=var, sentence)) count <- count +1
      }
      return(count)
   }
```

Second for the two averages, you can use the function in both cases:

```
average <- function(sentence, look_up)
{ 
  pattern <- look_up[,1]
  count <-0
  summed <- 0
  for (var in pattern)
  {
    if(grepl(pattern=var, sentence)) {
      count <- count + 1
      summed <- sum(look_up[look_up[,1]==var,2]) + summed
    }
  }        
  return(summed/count)
}
```

This you can apply to your data in this way:

First do:

```
desire_result <- data.frame(string = b$string)
```

Then to get the values do:

```
desired_result$num_match<- sapply(b$string,counter,pattern=a$term)
desired_result$avg_age<- sapply(b$string,average,look_up=a[,c(1,2)])
desired_result$avg_visit<- sapply(b$string,average,look_up=a[,c(1,3)])
```

This gives you now `desired_result` as mentioned in your question:

```
> desired_result
                                 string num_match  avg_age avg_visit
1      the red ball went over the fence         2 37.00000  3.500000
2 sorry to see that your tent fell down         1 73.00000  8.000000
3      the ball fell into the red salad         3 32.66667  2.666667
4 serious people eat peanuts on Sundays         0      NaN       NaN
```