# Get the Matched String?

Tags: r

I have two data frames, One has the product name & the other has the categories..now I need to match the category to the product name & assign respective categories to the names if the string is matched.

So 1st data frame containing the product name (Product_Name.csv) is:

```
           **Product.Name**
       Black Printed Blouse
Silver Embellished Crop Top
   Maroon Solid Strappy Top
```

The other data frame contaning the categories (Category.csv)is:

```
**Category**
     Strappy
      Blouse
        Crop
```

Final Output Should be:

```
       Black Printed Blouse       Blouse
Silver Embellished Crop Top         Crop
   Maroon Solid Strappy Top      Strappy
```

Now, I am using grepl which gives true or false

```
product <- read.csv("Product_Name.csv", header = T, sep = ",")
category <- read.csv("Category.csv", header = T, sep = ",")


for (i in 1:nrow(product)){

product[i, 2] <- grepl(Category$Category[1], product$Product.Name[i], ignore.case = TRUE)
product[i, 3] <- grepl(Category$Category[2], product$Product.Name[i], ignore.case = TRUE)
product[i, 4] <- grepl(Category$Category[3], product$Product.Name[i], ignore.case = TRUE)


}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String matching to data.frames of different sizes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39677987/string-matching-to-data-frames-of-different-sizes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
product$Category <- str_extract(product$Product.Name, paste(category$Category, collapse="|"))
product
#                 Product.Name Category
#1        Black Printed Blouse   Blouse
#2 Silver Embellished Crop Top     Crop
#3    Maroon Solid Strappy Top  Strappy
```

Answer (score 0):

using base - R

```
indices = sapply(category$Category, function(x) which(grepl(x, product$Product.Name)))

product$new_col = 1:nrow(product)
product$new_col[indices] = names(indices)
#> df
#            X..Product.Name.. new_col
#1        Black Printed Blouse  Blouse
#2 Silver Embellished Crop Top    Crop
#3    Maroon Solid Strappy Top Strappy
```

---

```
# incase of any no-match cases(which we need to handle well)
# below code manages both well (a generalised version)

category$Category[2] = "Bloiuse"

indices = sapply(category$Category, function(x) which(grepl(x, product$Product.Name)))
indices.loc <- as.numeric(indices)
indices.name <- names(indices)

product$new_col[indices.loc[!is.na(indices.loc)]] = indices.name[!is.na(indices.loc)]

#> product
#                 Product.Name new_col
#1        Black Printed Blouse    <NA>
#2 Silver Embellished Crop Top    Crop
#3    Maroon Solid Strappy Top Strappy
```